# MySQL: SUM with WHERE Clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with clients_id and payment data.
I try to sum all payments for `client_id` and filter results with `WHERE` Clause, using SQL query below:

```
SELECT client_id, SUM(payment) AS total_payment 
FROM table1 
WHERE total_payment >= 1000 
GROUP BY client_id
```

This query working without WHERE Clause only.
MySQL return error

> #1054 - Unknown column 'total_payment' in 'where clause'

Any pointers into the right direction would be helpful. Thanks!

**table1 example**

```
| client_id | payment |
| --------- | ------- |
| 001       | 2000    |
| 001       | 20      |
| 002       | 1000    |
| 003       | 300     |
| 003       | 100     |
| 004       | 900     |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at HAVING in a GROUP BY situation

```
SELECT client_id, SUM(payment) AS total_payment 
FROM table1 
GROUP BY client_id
HAVING total_payment >= 1000
```

Answer (score 1):

Your restriction on the sum aggregate belongs in a `HAVING` clause, not the `WHERE` clause:

```sql
SELECT client_id, SUM(payment) AS total_payment
FROM table1
GROUP BY client_id
HAVING total_payment >= 1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`

```
SELECT client_id, SUM(payment) AS total_payment 
FROM table1  
GROUP BY client_id
HAVING total_payment >= 1000
```